# Angular JS TypeError: $http is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angularjs-controller, angularjs-http

I have read through all the posts where people get this issue where $http is not a function, and it looks like for the most part it is due to injections being done in the wrong order.

My module definition looks like this:

```
angular.module("app", []).controller("appCtrl", ['$scope','$http',
    function ($scope, $http) {

...

    $scope.makeCall= function ($http) {
         console.log("HERE");
         $http({ method: 'GET', url: <url }).
            then(function (response) {

                console.log(response.data);
                return response.data;
            }, function (response) {

        });
    };
}
])
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try this $scope.makeCall= function () { ...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Remove `$http` parameter from `makeCall` function, which is killing the existence of `$http` dependency injected over controller. Basically when you are adding it on function, it is setted as `undefined`

```
$scope.makeCall= function () { //<-- removed $http dependency from here
   console.log("HERE");
   $http({ method: 'GET', url: 'url' })
      .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data);
            return response.data;
      }, function (response) {

      }
   );
};
```